# ReactEditText.<init> Crash on React Native 0.64.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

In my React Native Android application, I'm encountering a runtime error that I'm having trouble resolving. The error message is as follows:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable(android.content.res.Resources)' on a null object reference
```

The error occurs in the following stack trace:

```
android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.createAllFutures (DrawableContainer.java:880)
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init> (AppCompatEditText.java:65)
com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactEditText.<init> (ReactEditText.java:124)
com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager.createViewInstance (ReactTextInputManager.java:123)
com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager.createViewInstance (ReactTextInputManager.java:79)
com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createViewInstance (ViewManager.java:139)
com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView (ViewManager.java:83)
com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView (NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:281)
com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute (UIViewOperationQueue.java:188)
com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations (UIViewOperationQueue.java:1103)
com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded (UIViewOperationQueue.java:1074)
com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame (GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame (ReactChoreographer.java:175)
com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame (ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:973)
```

I've tried various debugging methods, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause of this error. It seems to be related to the creation of a React Native TextInput component.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before or can provide guidance on how to resolve this NullPointerException? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this exact same error, did you end up solving this?

Comment: Yes, solved. But i don't remember the solution, went through comments after comments in github. And used something like ->

In  android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml added
```
<item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
```
Added this file
https://github.com/ApollosProject/apollos-apps/blob/main/ApollosStorybook/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/rn_edit_text_material.xml